# Nopermissionsinaccess token error when trying to get calendar from graph API

Tags: c#, azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

there are other questions about this, but I've not seen my exact situation and I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

My app has a client secret set up and here are the api permissions

[image: Api examples]

My code is pretty simple

```
    var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

            
            var tenantId = "tenenantid";

           
            var clientId = "clientid";
            var clientSecret = "secret";

           
            var options = new TokenCredentialOptions
            {
                AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
            };

          
            var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
                tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);

            var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);


         
              var calendars = await graphClient.Users["userIdhere"].Events.Request()
              .GetAsync();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same via Postman by granting same permissions and got the error as below:***

[image]

**To resolve the error, make sure to grant `Application` permissions and grant admin consent as you are using client credentials grant flow:**

[image]

After granting the **`Application`** permissions, I got the list of calendar events successfully like below:

[image]

**Reference:**

[List events - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)